# Cross Compiling any tool for Arm

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I have cross-compiled Dropbear for an arm based device using the toolchain that came bundled with the device. I wonder if someone could tell me of a way to cross compile binaries to get a generic one, meaning the binary that will run on any Arm make?

Why I ask this question, because when we compile for Android, it works on every Arm make running Android OS (at least I am assuming it will).

Please correct me if what I am assuming is wrong and that there is no way what I am asking here is possible and/or if what I am asking here is completely absurd.

PS: I am no expert in cross compiling stuff, I have started to learn new things from the past couple of months and Stack Overflow has been my source for answers.

Comment: Purpose: I need to automate cross-compiling of several tools for several arm devices and I wonder if there is even a remote possibility of compiling a generic binary.

Comment: Is a meta-make system of some kind in use? cake? autoconf?

Comment: Eventually I will use cmake. Although I am compiling, for now, in terminal. Hope I answered your question.